# Call magento template via $this->getChildHtml()

Tags: magento

I have a contact form template (modal.phtml), which I want to add to all pages on my site, but I need to be able to position it precisely, so I want to insert into the relevant page templates using `$this->getChildHtml('contacts-modal')`, instead of inserting via layout xml. So in page/2columns-right.phtml, I want to use that call to insert the template stored in contacts/modal.phtml. The layout xml i have below is automatically inserting this template - how do i go about correcting this? Thanks for any pointers, and apologies if this is a very basic thing!

```
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contacts-modal" as="contacts-modal" template="contacts/modal.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you include it in the footer and position it via javascript?...just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the template with `$this->getChildHtml('contacts-modal')` you have to declare it in the layout xml, look into the class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract to see how getChildHtml works.
If you want to add it to other pages that don't have 2columns-right as main template, you have to add the xml reference like you did with 2columns-right, or you can use inside the parent template `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('contacts/modal.phtml')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emi. I was hoping to use your last suggestion there, but calling this from 2columns-right.phtml, for example, throws: Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Core_Block_Template could not be converted to string

Comment: All I needed was to add ->toHtml() to the end of that call. Working perfectly now, thanks