# Magento getChildHtml block not rendering

Tags: magento

I'm attempting to rearrange some elements on a webpage and my code won't render it its new position.

The top of the page is handled in view.phtml and the bottom in list.phtml.  I'm wanting to move form.phtml from view to list.

The xml looks like this:

```
     <block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                <action method="disableGallery"/>
            </block>
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml"/>
```

the view.phtml contains this call:

```
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
```

However, no dice.  I'm very new to Magento, so any help would be great. I've looked into the following questions and more with no results:

[Nested block within a reference not rendering when using ->getChildHtml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753991/nested-block-within-a-reference-not-rendering-when-using-getchildhtml)

[Magento $this->getChildHtml('media') return blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825127/magento-this-getchildhtmlmedia-return-blank)

[Call magento template via $this->getChildHtml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145921/call-magento-template-via-this-getchildhtml)

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I've gotten other things to render in the file, but not this call.

Answer (score 0):

As per as  your description,review child block is call in under view then...

it should be

```
     <block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                    <action method="disableGallery"/>
                </block>
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                            <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                            <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
.........
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I switched out the code but it still isn't showing.

Comment: Check review module is enable  or not